# How do you show and hide field in a form depending on drop-down selections?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, show-hide

I am trying to create a form in which would show and hide a specific field of a form when certain elements of a drop-down list is selected.

I currently have found a way to hide it using CSS but I am not sure on how you would use CSS or JavaScript to unhide them when specific values in the drop down list are selected.

This is what I have got at the moment:
HTML:

```html
    <td><label for="ageRange">Age: </label><font color="red">*</font></td>
    <td><select name="ageRange" id="ageRange">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="0-16">0-16</option>
            <option value="17-25">17-25</option>
            <option value="26-40">26-40</option>
            <option value="41-60">41-60</option>
            <option value="60+">61+</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="license" class="hidden">Driver's License: </label></td>
    <td><input type="test" name="license" id="license" class="hidden"><br></td>
```

CSS:

```css
    input.hidden {
        display: none
    }
    label.hidden {
        display: none
    }
```

What I want to happen is for the field "Driver's License" to stay hidden unless in the drop-down list (ageRange) you select any values except for "Select" and "0-16."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do so . Just check the selected value by dropdown and compare with value. If `selectedValue` found `0-16` just add `hidden class` on `tr` remove otherwise.

```js
document.getElementById("toHide").classList.add("hidden");

function myFunction(){
var selectedVal = document.getElementById("ageRange").value;
 if(selectedVal == "0-16" || selectedVal=="0" ){
   document.getElementById("toHide").classList.add("hidden");
    document.getElementById("license").value='';
  } else{
  document.getElementById("toHide").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.getElementById("license").value=selectedVal;
 }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
        display: none
    }
```

```html
<table border="2">
 <td><label for="ageRange">Age: </label><font color="red">*</font></td>
    <td><select name="ageRange" id="ageRange"  onchange="myFunction()">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="0-16">0-16</option>
            <option value="17-25">17-25</option>
            <option value="26-40">26-40</option>
            <option value="41-60">41-60</option>
            <option value="60+">61+</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="toHide">
    <td ><label for="license" >Driver's License: </label></td>
    <td ><input type="test"  name="license" value=""  id="license" ><br></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I have tried implementing this code but when I use onchange it doesn't call any functions from the JavaScript script. I tested this with another function I called "test()" and set it to alert("Successful") but it didn't call that function either. Do you know if there's anything I can do about this to fix it.

Comment: Nevermind I sorted the problem. JavaScript threw a couple of Syntax Errors I didn't see. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try onchange and get the value and add or remove class using the below code.

```js
function check(e){
  if(e.value != '0' && e.value != '0-16'){
      var lab = document.getElementById("licLab");
      lab.classList.remove("hidden");
      var txt = document.getElementById("license");
      txt.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
      var lab = document.getElementById("licLab");
      lab.classList.add("hidden");
      var txt = document.getElementById("license");
      txt.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
input.hidden {
    display: none
}
label.hidden {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<td><label for="ageRange">Age: </label><font color="red">*</font></td>
    <td><select name="ageRange" id="ageRange" onchange="check(this)">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="0-16">0-16</option>
            <option value="17-25">17-25</option>
            <option value="26-40">26-40</option>
            <option value="41-60">41-60</option>
            <option value="60+">61+</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="license" class="hidden" id="licLab">Driver's License: </label></td>
    <td><input type="test" name="license" id="license" class="hidden"><br></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
 $('.hidden').hide()
})

$('select').on('change',function(){
  if ((this.value == '0') || (this.value == '0-16')) {
    $('.hidden').hide()
  }
  else{
  $('.hidden').show()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <td><label for="ageRange">Age: </label><font color="red">*</font></td>
    <td><select name="ageRange" id="ageRange">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="0-16">0-16</option>
            <option value="17-25">17-25</option>
            <option value="26-40">26-40</option>
            <option value="41-60">41-60</option>
            <option value="60+">61+</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="license" class="hidden">Driver's License: </label></td>
    <td><input type="test" name="license" id="license" class="hidden"><br></td>
```

Comment: `Jquery` is not mentioned in question.

Comment: the question just says " Javascript " . vanilla or not, is not mentioned.